# IIS Search Engine Optimization and Canonical Url with Dynamic Image

Tags: iis, seo, dynamic-image-generation, canonical-link

I get the following error below for my dynamic image generator.  It can have any kind of width or height but SEO is complaining about it because it needs a canonical URL.  How can I do this with a dynamic image that isnt a page?

```
The page with URL "http://localhost/assets/images/99?w=125" can also be accessed by using URL "http://localhost/assets/images/99?w=100".
Search engines identify unique pages by using URLs.  When a single page can be accessed by using any one of multiple URLs, a search engine assumes that there are multiple unique pages. Use a single URL to reference a page to prevent dilution of page relevance. You can prevent dilution by following a standard URL format.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `canonical` URL can be specified in a HTTP header, too. See [RFC 6596](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6596#section-4), section 4:

> or alternatively, in the HTTP header field as specified in [Section 5 of [RFC5988]](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5988#section-5):
>
> `Link: <http://www.example.com/page.php?item=purse>; rel="canonical"`